# Is it possible to access Models in schedule.rb (whenever gem)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, whenever

I am performing some tests in a Ruby on Rails application using Whenever gem.

Is it possible to access Models from the schedule.rb file ?!

For example:

```
#Hard Worker
job = Job.find_by(name: 'Hard')

if job.status == 'active'
  every 4.minutes do
    runner 'HardWorker.perform_async'
  end
end
```

Just checked this and I encountered this error:

```
config/schedule.rb:2:in `initialize': undefined method `find_by' for Whenever::Job:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Many thanks !

Comment: Found this resource: http://blog.shivamdaryanani.com/blog/2013/11/09/create-dynamic-cron-jobs-in-rails/

Comment: In this context may not understand your Job model, let try with job = ::Job.find_by(name: 'Hard')

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you very much !